# Prove a Field is a commutative ring with identity

Tags: ring-theory

I was just introduced to rings and fields recently and am in need with help for the following proof.

Prove: A field $F$ is a commutative ring with identity and with at least two elements, such that for all $a \ne 0$ and $b \in F$, the equation $ax=b$ has a unique solution in $F$.

I have a few hints from earlier problems: proving that if $ab=ac$ then $b=c$ (set $a(b-c) = 0$, multiply by $a^{-1}$ to get $b=c$) and proving $ax=b$ has a unique solution by setting $x = a^{−1} b$.

I'm just having trouble putting two and two together here.

Comment: What is the definition of field that you have?

Comment: Straight from the book: "any set of elements that satisfies the field axioms for both addition and multiplication and is a commutative division algebra."

Comment: So what is the definition of division algebra that you have?

Comment: In so many words, a ring where all non-zero elements has a multiplicative inverse. By that definition, every field is also a division ring.

Comment: But is this all I say for the proof, using the above mentioned hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, suppose that $F$ is a field. Let's show that, for any $a,b\in F$, $a\neq 0$, the equation $ax=b$ has a unique solution.

Since $a\neq 0$, then $a$ is invertible, that is, exists $a^{-1}\in F$ such that $aa^{-1}=1$. Then $a(a^{-1}b)=(aa^{-1})b=1b=b$, so $(a^{-1}b)$ is a solution. Now, if $x\in F$ is another solution of $ax=b$ and $ay=b$, then, $x=1x=(a^{-1}a)x=a^{-1}(ax)=a^{-1}b$. This proves the uniqueness of the solution of $ax=b$. Also $F$ has at least two elements ($0$ and $1$).

Now, suppose $F$ is a commutative ring with at least two elements and such that $ax=b$ has an unique solution for all $a,b\in F$, $a\neq 0$. If $1=0$, then $F=\left\{0\right\}$ (prove this!), a contradiction. So $1\neq 0$. Also, in particular, given $a\neq 0$, there exists a unique $x\in F$ such that $ax=1$. This proves that $F$ is a field.